# Prove that $∩\mathcal H ⊆ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

This is Velleman's exercise 3.5.17:

Suppose $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal G$, and $\mathcal H$ are nonempty families of sets and for every $A ∈ \mathcal F$ and every $B ∈ \mathcal G$, $A ∪ B ∈ \mathcal H$. Prove that $∩\mathcal H ⊆ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$.

And here's my proof of it:

Proof. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $∩\mathcal H$. We now have two cases to consider:

Case 1. $x ∈ ∩\mathcal F$. Thus certainly $x ∈ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$.

Case 2. $x ∉ ∩\mathcal F$ which is equivalent to $∃A ∈ \mathcal F(x ∉ A$). From $∃A ∈ \mathcal F(x ∉ A$) and $x ∈ ∩\mathcal H$, we have $A ∉ \mathcal H$ from which we can conclude $B ∈ \mathcal H$. Since $B ∈ \mathcal H$ and $x ∈ ∩\mathcal H$, then $x ∈ ∩\mathcal G$. Ergo $x ∈ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$.

Since from the both cases we get $x ∈ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$ and $x$ was arbitrary, then $∩\mathcal H ⊆ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$.

Is my proof valid? *Particularly this part:* "From $∃A ∈ \mathcal F(x ∉ A$) and $x ∈ ∩\mathcal H$, we have $A ∉ \mathcal H$ from which we can conclude $B ∈ \mathcal H$".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 2, $B$ pops out from nothing, but your idea is right: it just needs a refinement.

Suppose $x\notin\bigcap\mathcal{F}$. This means there is $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $x\notin A$. Now, let $B\in\mathcal{G}$. By assumption, $A\cup B\in\mathcal{H}$, so $x\in A\cup B$. Since $x\notin A$, we conclude $x\in B$. Since $B$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{G}$, we have $x\in B$, for every $B\in\mathcal{G}$. Hence $x\in\bigcap\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: I can see where exactly my problem was now! Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Particularly the part you are unsure about is not valid, so at least congratulations on seeing the problem.

Instead, I suggest to argue that if $x\notin\bigcap\mathcal F\cup \bigcap\mathcal G$, then $x\notin \bigcap\mathcal F$ and $x\notin\bigcap\mathcal G$, i.e., there exists $A\in\mathcal F$ with $x\notin A$ and $B\in\mathcal G$ with $x\notin B$. For these, $x\notin A\cup B$ and consequently $x\notin \bigcap \mathcal H$.

Comment: So, a proof by contradiction? That seems reasonable...! Thanks a lot.