# Prove that $\bigcap\mathcal H\subseteq(\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove that $∩\mathcal H ⊆ (∩\mathcal F) ∪ (∩\mathcal G)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400614/prove-that-%e2%88%a9-mathcal-h-%e2%8a%86-%e2%88%a9-mathcal-f-%e2%88%aa-%e2%88%a9-mathcal-g)

This is exercise $3.5.17$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal G$, and $\mathcal H$ are nonempty families of sets and for every $A\in\mathcal F$ and every $B\in\mathcal G$, $A\cup B\in\mathcal H$. Prove that $\bigcap\mathcal H\subseteq(\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$.

Here is my proof:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcap\mathcal H$. Now we consider two different cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $x\in\bigcap\mathcal F$. Therefore $x\in (\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $x\notin \bigcap\mathcal F$. So we can choose some $A_0$ such that $A_0\in\mathcal F$ and $x\notin A_0$. From $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cup B\in\mathcal H)$  and $A_0\in\mathcal F$, it follows that $A_0\cup B\in\mathcal H$ for every $B\in\mathcal G$. Since $x\in\bigcap\mathcal H$, $x\in A_0\cup B$ for every $B\in\mathcal G$. Since $x\notin A_0$, $x\in B$ for every $B\in\mathcal G$ and so $x\in\bigcap \mathcal G$. Thus $x\in (\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$.

Since the above cases are exhaustive, $x\in (\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$. Therefore if $x\in\bigcap\mathcal H$ then $x\in (\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x\Bigr(x\in\bigcap\mathcal H\rightarrow x\in (\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)\Bigr)$ and so $\bigcap\mathcal H\subseteq(\bigcap\mathcal F)\cup(\bigcap\mathcal G)$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate or not, but the top answer to the question you link to in the beginning essentially suggests the same line of proof as the one you're using (which is correct and valid, by the way).

Comment: @ChubbyChef I am self studying the material with no access to any real person to help me. So I need to become sure that my proofs are correct if I do them from scratch on my own.

Comment: that's perfectly fine. Good luck and enjoy your mathematical journey!

Comment: @ChubbyChef Thank you. $:)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is okay.

It is more handsome though to prove the contrapositive statement:$$x\notin\left(\bigcap\mathcal{F}\right)\cup\left(\bigcap\mathcal{G}\right)\implies x\notin\bigcap\mathcal{H}$$

---

Proof:

If $x\notin\left(\bigcap\mathcal{F}\right)\cup\left(\bigcap\mathcal{G}\right)$
then some $A\in\mathcal{F}$ exists $x\notin A$ and some $B\in\mathcal{G}$
exists with $x\notin B$.

Then $x\notin A\cup B\in\mathcal{H}$ so
we conclude that $x\notin\bigcap\mathcal{H}$.